# Convert contents of object to one entry in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object and I would like to convert the contents of the object as a string to first array element value , key of the array will be 0

example:
I have

```
const obj1= {
all-exception: []
root-exception: "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException\n"
timestamp: 1671113624318
truncated: false
}
```

I would like to see the result as :

```
const obj2= 
0: "{\"all-exceptions\":[],\"root-exception\":\"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException\\n\",\"timestamp\": 1671113624318,\"truncated\":false}”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the

```js
const obj = {
  'all-exception': [],
  'root-exception': "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException\n",
  timestamp: 1671113624318,
  truncated: false
};

console.log([JSON.stringify(obj)]);
```

`JSON.stringify` method:

Comment: I need the result as an array its a string

Comment: No, it is an array, don't you see the square brackets around it?